# python Exporting Postgres table csv Absolute vs Relative Path Copy To \copy Ubuntu linux OS

Tags: python, postgresql, path, absolute

I cant get my code to write a csv file from a postgres table.  The error I am getting is

**InvalidName: relative path not allowed for COPY to file**

My research suggests that an absolute path would be something that follows the directories to /home.  I have tried multiple paths and suggestions.  The most frequent solutions in my research and trials are...

/home/user/tmp/filename.csv

and

/tmp/filename.csv

and

/var/tmp/filename.csv

Here is the function that I am calling that generates the error...

```
    def copy_signals_table(self):
        now = datetime.date(datetime.now())
        filename = "/home/user/tmp/" + str(now) + ".csv"
        print(filename)
        self.cursor.execute("COPY table_name TO '"' filename '"' 
        DELIMITER ',' CSV;")
        #self.cursor.execute('''copy (SELECT * FROM table_name) to 
        #'filename' with csv''')
```

I have tried other means to save the file in the specified location with out any issues which confirms that there is no issue with the filename.

Any suggestions?

HERE IS A REVISED FUNCTION:

```
def copy_signals_table(self):
    now = datetime.date(datetime.now())
    sql = "COPY daily_signals TO '/home/alpha/tmp/" + str(now) + ".csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
    #sql = "\copy (SELECT * FROM daily_signals) TO '/home/alpha/tmp/" + str(now) + ".csv' with DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER"
    print(sql)
    self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

When I run the COPY code I get the following error--

**UndefinedFile: could not open file "/home/alpha/tmp/2020-05-20.csv" for writing: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.**

When I run the /copy code I get the following error--

**SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \copy (SELECT * FROM daily_signals) TO '/home/alpha/tmp/2020...**

Comment: note that `\copy` is special syntax supported by the `psql` command line client, not by the server itself.  this will therefore never work through psycopg2 (assuming you're using that) and you need something else.  a plain `COPY TO STDOUT` actually means to transfer over the connection to the server (which is stdout in `psql` hence where the syntax came from) which lets your code do something with it

Comment: @Sam , that is fantastic information but a digression from the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM tbl) TO '/var/lib/postgres/filename.csv' format csv;
```

According to:

[Manual Copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually putting that file name into the SQL to execute.

try printing the SQL:

```
    def copy_signals_table(self):
        now = datetime.date(datetime.now())
        filename = "/home/user/tmp/" + str(now) + ".csv"
        print(filename)
        sql = "COPY table_name TO '"' filename '"' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
        print(sql)
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

and I think you'll see: `"COPY table_name TO ' filename ' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"`

you might mean:

```py
        sql = "COPY table_name TO '" filename "' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
```

which might be closer to what you want.

Comment: I am still getting the same error with your suggestion.  I think the error  is something related to the file system which I am trying to develop a better understanding of.

Comment: what SQL was actually printed out?

Comment: yes, the print(sql) was a good suggestion, thanks.  However, I am still generating errors.   I have added a revised function and the errors I am getting above.

Comment: \copy (SELECT * FROM daily_signals) TO '/home/alpha/tmp/2020-05-20.csv' with DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER

Comment: the line above was printed

Comment: and what do you make of the error?  does `/home/alpha/tmp` exist on the database server or on your machine?  you might need to use `cursor.copy_expert` if you're copying from a server to your local machine

Comment: The code and the db are all written and run on an Ubuntu laptop.  When everything is working i transfer code to the actual server.

Comment: This is the error I get with cursor.copy_expert ...                                                                                                                                TypeError: Required argument 'file' (pos 2) not found

Comment: @Ludlow_Luddite see https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert for the docs

Comment: ok, but I suspect the issue is with the file organisational system and the related posgres permissions

Answer (score 0):

Here is the functioning function code...

```
def copy_signals_table(self):
    now = datetime.date(datetime.now())
    self.cursor.execute("copy (SELECT * FROM table_name) TO '/var/tmp/" + str(now) + ".csv' with DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;")
```

Simple and elegant, yes?  The issue was 1.) the permission file extention , 2.) the sql cut and paste syntax and 3.) COPY vs \copy syntax.  I was able eliminate one of the elements by typing the commands directly into the db command line.  After a few trial and errors I was able to work out the bugs.